# How to send message when Websocket opened on Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

I created `WebsocketHandler` as it was shown in the [Webflux websocket doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-websocket-server-handler).

```
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
    Flux<String> messages = 
            session.receive()
                    .map(webSocketMessage -> "New message");
    return session.send(messages.map(session::textMessage));
  }
```

But the problem is, I want to send some kind of `"Hello"` message right after the websocket connection opened. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found that, this can be solved with the Flux itself. It is enough that we add [`startWith`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#startWith-T%2E%2E%2E-) method to the `Flux`. As in the definition of the `startWith` method.

> Prepend the given values before this Flux sequence.

So we prepend our `Hello` message to the start of the `Flux` and it will be published first.

```
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
    Flux<String> messages = 
            session.receive()
                    .map(webSocketMessage -> "New message")
                    .startWith("Hello");
    return session.send(messages.map(session::textMessage));
  }
```

P.S. Bear in mind that you can also prepend `Publisher<? extends T> publisher` i.e. `Flux` or `Mono`, not just plain values.